# String to integer using recursion C++

Tags: c++, string, recursion, integer

```
int toInteger(const string& str, int count,int&value){
   if(str.length() == 1) {
      value += (str[0] - '0')*pow(10,count);
      return value;
   }
   else{
      value +=(str[str.length()-1] - '0')*pow(10,count);
      cout << value << endl << str << endl;
      toInteger(str.substr(0,str.length()-1),count+1,value);
   }
   return value;
}

int main(){
   string str;
   cout << "Enter String : ";
   cin >> str;
   int count = 0;
   int value = 0;
   int toint = toInteger(str, count, value);
   cout << toint << endl;   
}
```

This function is suppose to get a string input str and then return an integer version of the string using recursion.

"`Str`" is string
"`count`" is power multiplier :: initially 0
"`value`" is the return value :: initially 0

However the problem with this program in this function seems to appear after the string is at least length 3.:

If my string input is "12",  then i get in return the value 12.

If my string input is "123", then i get in return the value 122. (how did the function subtract one?

If my string input is "1234", then i get in return the value 1233. (yet again subtracted one)

Comment: Works for me - assuming you call it with 0 for `count` to start. Is this the exact right code?

Comment: You sure you're not just passing in -1 for `value` to start?

Comment: Confident that value = 0. If value was -1 having a string length of 2 "12" would be 11

Comment: [The code in your question works](http://ideone.com/MVIXkd).  What you're showing us doesn't explain why you're getting `122`.

Comment: I can also verify that the code indeed works.

Comment: Enter String : 1234 . 
1233 . 

I agree however this  is my output .  http://puu.sh/f5pvr.png

Comment: @user3249265 What that means is that we can probably rule out a problem in your code.  There probably is an issue with your compiler or your environment.

Comment: The code does seem to work. One more question: Why do you return the value if you are passing it by reference??

Comment: @Drew Dormann I guess there's something wrong on my computer end. I'm a little confused but thankyou.

Comment: @python_user umm if i understand the question right, i did that so value is kept throughout each iteration.

Comment: wait, are you adding the period on the end that you show in your comment? Because when I do, I get a much weirder answer. Also, any extra spaces - because you're not checking your input chars for whether they're numeric or not - would give similar oddball effects

Comment: @user3249265 You can also pass it by reference

Comment: @user3249265 I think I know what it is... you're using `pow` which does not work on integers.  You may be getting a result like `122.999999` cast to an `int`.

Comment: i will double check right now with a double value then cast it to int.

Comment: changing both(10.0,count) to double then casting into int does not help

Comment: @Drew Dormann i changed EVERYTHING to double and it worked, you were right. Please comment answer so i can check this question off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversions from a floating-point type to an integer type round toward zero.

If you have a floating point value that is ***very*** close to 123...but not quite, you'll lose all of that fractional value and end up with 122.

That applies here.

```
  value += (str[0] - '0')*pow(10,count);
```

Try making a **very rudimentary** integer version of `pow` for your function to use.  Just to test it.

```
int pow( int x, int y )
{
  int result = 1;
  while ( y-- ) result *= x;
  return x;
}

int toInteger(const string& str, int count,int&value){
   if(str.length() == 1) {
      value += (str[0] - '0')*pow(10,count);
      return value;
   }
   else{
      value +=(str[str.length()-1] - '0')*pow(10,count);
      cout << value << endl << str << endl;
      toInteger(str.substr(0,str.length()-1),count+1,value);
   }
   return value;
}
```

This version has no conversions between integral and floating-point types.  And as a result, **no rounding**.

Comment: In that case, however, either his compiler, C runtime or CPU is buggy, because integral values are exactly representable in floats.

Comment: Thankyou again. I Changed the return value to double then casted it as int in the main body fixed the problem.

Comment: @Dolda2000 something approximating "buggy", I would suspect.  Yes.  I don't know what kind of accuracy `pow` promises.

Comment: @user3249265 keep in mind that if you have `float`<->`int` conversions, you still risk these off-by-one errors.  I recommend never converting to floats for math that can be represented with `int`s

Comment: @DrewDormann: I'll admit I may have been a bit naive anyway. I assumed that `pow()` should return an exact result for integer arguments, but searching around shows that there is actually no such guarantee. So I guess it's fair to say that this failure mode is valid after all. Though it does make me curious what environment this is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how your code actually works (as stated by several in the comments), this is not actually an answer to your question as such, but I should point out that your function is needlessly complex and loses half the point of recursion by using shared mutable state between invocations.

It can be made more simple and elegant as such:

```
int toInteger(const string& str) {
    if(str.length() == 0)
         return 0;
    return str[str.length() - 1] - '0' +
        toInteger(str.substr(0, str.length() - 1)) * 10;
}
```

Comment: i saw a version of this program do it that way, however i didn't understand  the return call. Looking at it now it makes sense. I was thinking about how i needed to get a power of 10 for each string character so i went ahead with power. Thank you.

Comment: not sure why the downvote? It doesn't answer user's direct question (so I'd not upvote it), but it does attempt to answer the question implied by the OP's actual question.

Comment: it wasn't me that did that!